# How to Customize Format HTTP JSON POST Request in VB

Tags: vb.net, linq, post, json.net

This is the end result {"recordType": "b", "recordNumber": 1550316, "pickupLocation": "de"}

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    'GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    If e.CommandName = "Hold" Then
        'Determine the RowIndex of the Row whose Button was clicked.
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

        'Reference the GridView Row.
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(rowIndex)

        'Fetch values.
        Dim recordId As String = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblRecordId"), Label).Text
        Dim recordType As String = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblrecordType"), Label).Text
        Dim homeCode As String = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblHomeCode"), Label).Text
      Dim input As Object = New With {
           .recordType =  recordType ,
           .recordNumber = recordId,
           .pickupLocation =  homeCode 
    }


      Dim inputJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input)
      Dim request3 As HttpWebRequest
      Dim response3 As HttpWebResponse = Nothing

      request3 = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("SOMEURL"), HttpWebRequest)
            request3.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            request3.Accept = "application/json"
            request3.ContentType = "application/json"
            request3.Method = "POST"

      Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputJson)



     Using stream As Stream = request3.GetRequestStream()
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                stream.Flush()
                stream.Close()
          End Using
      Using httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = 
      DirectCast(request3.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                Using stream As Stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream()
                    'lblOutput.Text = (New StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
         End If
      End Sub
```

InputJson = "{""recordType"":""b"",""recordNumber"":""1550316"",""pickupLocation"":""de""}"

which returns = "httpStatus": 400,
  "name": "Invalid JSON",
  "description": "JSON object missing field or field has invalid data"

I need help correctly formatting my post request to look like the following please note the the recordnumber value does not have quotes.->

```
{"recordType": "b", "recordNumber": 1550316, "pickupLocation": "de"}
```

TY :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that recordId is a string type.

Option 1: Make a concrete class and get away from the anonymous type.

```
Public Class YourClass
    Public Property recordType As String
    Public Property recordNumber As Integer
    Public Property pickupLocation As String
End Class
```

Option 2: If you're *SURE* this is an Integer then just convert it to such when you are initializing your anonymous type.

```
    Dim input As Object = New With {
                .recordType = "b",
                .recordNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(recordId),
                .pickupLocation = "de"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer N0Alias.  Option 2: Manage to get rid of the quotes around the recordNumber -> "{""recordType"":""b"",""recordNumber"":1550316,""pickupLocation"":""de""}" . any idea on how to fix the quotes  outside of the {} and replace the double quotes inside with the {} with single "